# Acceptance-Rejection Method Acceptance Probability Proof

Tags: self-study, sampling, rejection-sampling

I did not fully understand the proof of the acceptance probability.

The acceptance-rejection algorithm is described as follows:

- suppose you have RVs $X$ and $Y$ with densities $f$ and $g$, respectively, and there exists a constant $c$ such that $\frac{f(t)}{g(t)} \leq c$ for all $t$ such that $f(t) > 0$, then

  1. generate random $y$ from distribution with density $g$
  2. generate random $u$ from $\text{Uniform}(0, 1)$
  3. if $u < \frac{f(y)}{cg(y)}$ accept $y$ and deliver $x = y$, otherwise repeat

In Rizzo's book 'Statistical Computing with R' (p56) he writes

$P(\text{accept}|Y)=P(U<\frac{f(Y)}{cg(Y)}|Y)=\frac{f(Y)}{cg(Y)}$

and so

$\sum_y{P(\text{accept}|y)P(Y=y)}=\sum_y{\frac{f(y)}{cg(y)}g(y)}=\frac{1}{c}$

This still makes sense to me, but what about the continuous version of this proof, which is as follows:

$
\begin{aligned}
P(A) =& \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dy\int_0^{\frac{f(y)}{cg(y)}}g(y)du \\
=& \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{c}f(y)dy \\
=& \frac{1}{c}.
\end{aligned}
$

Could someone explain to me specifically how you get to this double integral?

Comment: By not explaining the notation you are making your readers work harder than they need to, so consider describing the meanings of $f$, $g$, and $A.$  As far as the double integral goes, your understanding might benefit from a method that almost always helps: draw a picture of the region it describes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you target $f$ with $g$, and you know $f(x) \le g(x)c$, then
\begin{align*}
P(\text{accept proposal}) &= P\left( U \le \frac{f(X)}{g(X)c} \right) \\
&= E\left( \mathbf{1}\left[U \le \frac{f(X)}{g(X)c}\right] \right) \tag{*}\\
&= E\left( E\left[ \mathbf{1}\left\{U \le \frac{f(X)}{g(X)c}\right\} \bigg\rvert X \right]\right) \\
&= E\left( P\left[ U \le \frac{f(X)}{g(X)c} \bigg\rvert X \right]\right) \\
&= E\left( \frac{f(X)}{g(X)c} \right) \\
&= c^{-1}\int f(x)g(x)/g(x) \text{d}x \\
&= c^{-1}.
\end{align*}

Note that (*) is a double integral because both $U$ and $X$ are random, so you must integrate their joint density over the appropriate region. They are independent, so their joint density factors, so the joint density is $f_U(u)g_X(x) = 1 \cdot g(x) = g(x)$. There is no $u$ in this expression because it is a uniform random variable--just make sure you integrate over the right bounds.

Comment: Correct though your answer is, I think the OP's question is really about where the double integral in the first line of $P(A) = \dots$ comes from and how it works to get to the final result, not about the broader move from summation to integration.

Comment: @jbowman ah that's right. I went a little quick. Hopefully this change takes care of that. I also thought that that first line of OP's was just a mistake, but now I see I've clarified it for the both of us.